# Debugging python with VSCode leads to incompatible architecture error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have setup VSCode on an M1 ARM apple laptop. Using the terminal I can launch my python project just fine, however when I try to debug via VSCode I end up with:

incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')

It appears to activate the same virtualenv in the terminal and inside VSCode.

In the error output I noticed: "File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module"

[image]

Is it maybe using the wrong python, ie. not the virtualenv python? Is there anyway I can tell VSCode which python to use?

If I run "where python" I get "/usr/bin/python" and if I run "where python3" I get:
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3

Comment: Could you provide more error information? Such as attaching a screenshot. And on the bottom-left of the VSCode, you can get which python interpreter you are using or you can execute the command of `get-command python` in the PowerShell or `where python` in the cmd.

Comment: thx for getting back to me here. I added a screenshot.

Comment: It looks there are some problems with the package of `pydantic`, could you try to reinstall this package?

Comment: For a start, create a [mcve] as usual. I guess you simply created the venv (or some per-user installed PIPs) and then copied it to a different architecture. Also, please don't use images of text, just put the text into your question so people find it during a search.

Comment: I installed the venv using pipenv

Comment: ok .. I created the reproducible example but didn't find any issues. I then noticed that in my test case I was using python 3.9, so I switched my problem project from 3.8 to 3.9 and it seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this issue by running the script from terminal (Rosetta or arm) ([link](https://www.courier.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-to-setup-your-apple-m1-for-development/)) and debugging via command line ([link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging/#_command-line-debugging)).

Note: Please make sure the dependencies are installed in the rosetta or arm terminal.

On the terminal, we can execute the python script.

```
python -m debugpy --listen 5678 ./myscript.py
```

And we need to add the launch.json configuration in VS Code.

```
{
  "name": "Python: Attach",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "attach",
  "connect": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5678
  }
}
```